Custom Python module requires subfolders
I have a custom Python module where all the .py files used to be in the same folder as setup.py, allowing me to import them directly (e.g. import AliasColourFunctions). Recently, this setup no longer works, and I now have to use the import statement with the module name as a prefix (e.g. import AliasNewPythonModules.AliasColourFunctions).
I want to continue importing these files directly without needing to specify the module name. Is there a way to fix this?
The folder contents are:

AliasColourFunctions.py,
AliasGeneralFunctions.py,
AliasSillyBillyFunctions.py,
AliasTkFunctions.py,
README.md,
setup.py,
init.py (Empty)


You could for example import all functions in the folders __init__.py. So change the content of __init__.py to:
from AliasColourFunctions import *
That should make it possible to use every function which is in AliasColourFunctions.py directly.

I've resorted to putting them all in seperate folders as init files, even if I don't like it.
